# PHP & MySQL Calling Data With a LEFT JOIN in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Simple question here, but I'm creating a forum and on the 'Category view' page I have a table with links to each topic in that category, I also have the date each topic was posted. My issue is, I'm trying to display the person who posted the topic's username. My code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics t LEFT JOIN users AS u ON t.topic_by=u.user_id WHERE t.topic_cat = :topicCat";
$query = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':topicCat' => $catid));
...
echo '<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Topic</th>
                <th>Posted by</th>
                <th>Created on</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>';
        while ($topicRow = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<tr>
                <td>
                    <h3><a href="topic.php?id=' . $topicRow['u.user_name'] . '">' . $topicRow['topic_subject'] . '</a></h3>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="user.php?id=' . $topicRow['topic_by'] . '"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    ' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($topicRow['topic_date'])) . '
                </td>
            </tr>';
        }

        echo '</table>';
```

$catid is already defined from a $_GET variable, the problem is the `<a href="topic.php?id=' . $topicRow['u.user_name'] . '">'`. I can't seem to link the two tables although they already have a foreign key link. See my db here:[image: DB Layout]

This is the error I'm getting right now:

> Notice: Undefined index: u.user_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBSITE\category.php on line 41

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think calling `SELECT *` will retain the `u` alias in the DB driver's associative array keys, so try `$topicRow['user_name']` instead.

Comment: Exactly.  If your query does not work as expected you can try running it in phpMyAdmin or a MySQL console (in shell) to see what it's returning.

Comment: just remove the `AS` in `users AS u` in your sql statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PHP returns the columns from the MySQL call it does NOT include the table prefix in the call.  So `$topicRow['u.user_name']` should just be `$topicRow['user_name']`.

If you had multiple columns after the JOIN by the name `user_name` then you'd want to specify which in the SELECT part, like `SELECT *,u.user_name AS user_name,...`